# How to extract the correlation score from mixOmics CIM?

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to extract what I call the "correlation score" used to fill the Color Key legend in CIM plots (mixOmics package in R) to put it in a vector. I mean by correlation score the corresponding number of the different colors used in the "Color key" legend, that is to say for example "-7" corresponds to deep blue and "+7" corresponds to red. There must be a matrix of the corresponding numbers that I would extract.
[Here is an example of CIM plot to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0J8M.png). The example plot is from the mixOmics CIM tutorial [here](http://mixomics.org/case-studies/spls-liver-toxicity/).

I plotted several CIM for several time points and would like to plot the evolution of this score through time (between a specific X against a specific Y).

I looked at the results of the function used by the cim function (spls in my case) but didn't find these numbers. I also checked the cim function itself ([cim function code](https://github.com/cran/mixOmics/blob/master/R/cim.R)) but couldn't find what was used to fill this plot.

Comment: what do other people call the "correlation score". If there's a specific metric you have in mind...

Comment: Hello Dan, what I call "correlation score" would rather be the "correlation coefficient", in my case it might be a Pearson's correlation coefficient.

Comment: Hope that answered the question for you! If it did, please mark it as the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not provided for you as a component of the object produced by `cim`. You can calculate the correlation coefficient yourself, using the same method the source for `cim` does, which is `cor(as.matrix(<the object you passed to cim>), method = "pearson")`

If you want to find where they calculate it in the source code, just search for "pearson" in [the source code you linked to](https://github.com/cran/mixOmics/blob/master/R/cim.R).

Comment: Thanks, doesn't work in that way but gives me a good clue of where to dig !

Answer (score 0):

If you save the output of the `cim` function you would get a list which also includes the correlation scores. See example below:

```r
suppressMessages(library(mixOmics))
data(nutrimouse)
X <- nutrimouse$lipid
Y <- nutrimouse$gene
## create the model
nutri.rcc <- rcc(X, Y, ncomp = 3, lambda1 = 0.064, lambda2 = 0.008)
## run CIM
cim.res <- cim(nutri.rcc, xlab = "genes", ylab = "lipids", margins = c(5, 6))
## the estimated correlation scores
cim.res$mat[1:5,1:5]
#>                CYP24         UCP3         RARb2           MS        RXRg1
#> C22.4n.6 -0.01999813 -0.021422216 -0.0008888194 -0.057980829 -0.074168260
#> C20.2n.6  0.01671939  0.019221066  0.0071498086  0.005241631 -0.005110272
#> C18.2n.6 -0.03887285 -0.029912475 -0.0629494996 -0.019159813 -0.028949622
#> C20.1n.9  0.11292746  0.111650764  0.0896226940  0.107370773  0.110154733
#> C18.3n.3 -0.01226061 -0.007427514 -0.0293529129  0.006002495  0.004682637
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>